# Find the sum of an infinite series

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

How can I find the sum of an infinite series?

[image]

Series:

My misbehaving example:

```
seq 0 inf | awk '{sum+=(1/$1)} END {print sum}'
```

Is it possible to carry out this method correct calculation or how to resolve this problem in other ways?

Comment: Do you need to do it in a finite time ? If so, do you have information on its convergence ?

Comment: I would suggest starting from 1, as 1/0 will break it. Also, use `printf "%f\n", sum` as per floating values.

Comment: @fedorqui I hope in any case this sum is just an example, as it doesn't converge.

Comment: @dystroy convergent or non-convergent, you can never sum an infinite series this way

Comment: Yes it is just an example. I would not prevent any working example.

Comment: @behzad.nouri You can in some cases if you know how it converges, hence my first comment. Any computation is to a given precision.

Comment: @dystroy plz give me an example where you can sum over `seq 0 inf`. like would `1 / ( $1 * $1 )` work? i think 1/n^2 is convergent, right?

Comment: Consider looking at [GNU octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

Comment: @dystroy, can be an example in the form of code?

Comment: 1+ for doing numerics using the shell. :-))

Comment: The sum of an infinite series can only be determined (exactly) via analysis, not computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This series does not converge. It's called the harmonic series and it's known to do not converge.

Moreover, as a comment says, you need to start at 1 instead of 0 because otherwise it's not defined (division by 0).

Try this:

```
seq 1 inf | awk '{sum+=(1/$1)} {print sum}'
```

However, this doesn't work well for higher iterations, because number format representations are not compatible and the precision of the internally used number representation is not sufficient.

To make more precise calculations for estimating the value of a convergent series, you should use a scientific calculation package of a better suited programming language like Java, Python or C++.

Here is a complete working example in Java:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class SeriesCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(100, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

        BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        while (true) {
            // calculation for every iteration
            BigDecimal element = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(i, mathContext);
            sum = sum.add(element);

            // show output once for every magnitude
            String iStr = i.toString();
            if (iStr.matches("10*")) {
                int log10_i = iStr.length() - 1;
                System.out.println("i=10^" + log10_i + "; sum = " + sum);
            }

            // preparation of next iteration step
            i = i.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i=10^0; sum = 1
i=10^1; sum = 2.9289682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682539682540
i=10^2; sum = 5.18737751763962026080511767565825315790897212670845165317653395658721955753255049660568776892312041358
i=10^3; sum = 7.485470860550344912656518204333900176521679169708803665773626749957699349165202440959934437411845081421
i=10^4; sum = 9.7876060360443822641784779048516053348592629455776917183894609566816020249431595068001251272900808826142
i=10^5; sum = 12.09014612986342794736321936350421950079369894178220110162752941593818198228230919443164900701935230601448
i=10^6; sum = 14.392726722865723631381127493188587676644800013744311653418433045812958507517995003568298175947219100731214
i=10^7; sum = 16.6953113658598518153991189395404518842498697523730804627851359543562886921742546877116037143701502883133367
i=10^8; sum = 18.99789641385389832441711039422398284185097124497010343881842218865761130260918292544757982666365581248865345
...
```

Comment: I assumed it was just an example (see comments below the question).

Comment: I actually don't know. Let's see if the OP clarifies.

Comment: Just remove the `END` to see it keep growing.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've improved the answer.